# XNA model translation is bizzarre

Tags: vb.net, 3d, xna, camera

When using `Matrix.CreateTranslation(x,y,z)` I get bizarre results. I have tested using fixed values, one variable at a time and have determined the following:

- When altering the X coordinates, the model moves from the top left corner to the bottom right corner.
- When altering the Y coordinates, the model moves up and down as it should.
- I do not plan to alter the Z coordinates, but because of the nature of my program I can't figure out exactly what it does.

I have my model drawn. Rotation works fine. I am performing my translations in the correct order (at least I think): `scale * rotation * translation`.

I think the problem lies in my camera settings, but I have no idea exactly what the problem is. I am trying to create a top-down-style RTS camera.

Here are my camera settings:

```
campos = new Vector3(5000.0F, 5000.0F, 5000.0F)
effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(campos, Vector3.Down, Vector3.Up)
```

I can provide more information as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of [Matrix.CreateLookAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195650.aspx) is not the direction the camera is facing, but the targeted point.

If you try to make the camera look down, use

```
Matrix.CreateLookAt(campos, campos + Vector3.Down, Vector3.Forward)
```

This will tell the camera to always look at the point one unit below the camera.

Your translation probably doesn't work well because the camera is not looking at the point you want it to, and therefore looks like the model is moving diagonally.

Comment: OK, previously when I tried this my model wouldn't show up at all. I have since fixed that but the translation issue still remains. I add 5 to the X position every tick and it moves towards the bottom right corner of the screen.